# angular - assign a variable when array filter is completed

Tags: angular

In one angular component, I am trying to put progress spinner over data loading. User click on html button and below function executes. Array filter may take some time depending upon array size. I want variable isLoading to be true in the beginning and false when filter function is completed. Variable isLoading  is used to show/hide progress spinner.

```
myfunction(val){
    this.isLoading = true   
    var data =  this.myarray.filter(function(item) { 
      // this.isLoading = false // tried this, throws error - Cannot set property 'isLoading' of undefined     
      return item.name == val;      
    });
    this.showdata = data[0]
    // this.isLoading = false // tried this, but this does not show effect
}
```

Please suggest, how to handle this.
Thanks

Comment: and `this` inside `(function(item) {` will be this of the anonymous function. use lambda function to use outside/parent this.

Comment: "_tried this, but this does not show effect_" Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is not an asynchronous method, your program will wait till its completion. You simply have to remove the `this.isLoading = false` from inside the filter:

```
this.isLoading = true;
var data =  this.myarray.filter(function(item) { 
      return item.name == val;      
    });
this.isLoading = false;
```

`this` has a different context inside the function, and is not the same as that object referred to by the outer `this`

Comment: I need to make "isLoading" true in beginning. I tried your suggestion but this.isLoading = false;immediately overwrites the value and does not wait for filter to completed.

Comment: I have edited the answer, included an assignment statement at the start. I hope that helps

Comment: my mistake. I should have mentioned that this function is part of one angular component. It unnecessarily created confusion of <this>. edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because functions in JavaScript has their own context, meaning `this` inside the function that does the filtering is different than the one inside the `myfunction`.

To pass the context to another function you can use bind.

```js
myfunction(val){
    this.isLoading = true   
    var data =  this.myarray.filter((function(item) { 
       this.isLoading = false;
      /* ... */
    }).bind(this));
    /* ... */
}
```

Alternatively if your environment support ES6 or you're using babel you can use arrow functions instead:

```js
myfunction(val){
    this.isLoading = true   
    var data =  this.myarray.filter((item) => { 
       this.isLoading = false;
      /* ... */
    });
    /* ... */
}
```

This will fix the error, but won't achieve your desired behavior because as @VedantBang in his answer mentioned that the filter method is not asynchronous.

What you could do:

```js
myfunction(val){
    this.isLoading = true;
    setTimeout((function() {
      var data =  this.myarray.filter(function(item) { 
         return item.name == val;      
      });
      this.showdata = data[0]
      this.isLoading = false;
    }).bind(this), 1000 /* Simulate 1000 milliseconds delay */);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await for this

```
async myfunction(val){
    this.isLoading = true   
    var data = await getFilteredData();
    this.showdata = data[0]
    this.isLoading = false
}

getfilteredData(){
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {     
      resolve(this.myarray.filter((item) item.name === val));      
    });
  }
```

Now when the filtered data will be returned only then the `isLoading` will be set to false